# how to retrieve title In listview

Tags: android, listview

guys i found this Shopping cart example though it is amazing exmaple for implementing Shopping  Cart example
http://www.androiddom.com/2011/06/android-shopping-cart-tutorial-part-2.html

Can you tell me how to get Title of all books Selected when i click on button "PROCEED TO CHECKOUT"

please help me out with this i tried alot but not able to get
PS:As  code is too big i am not to paste it here please take the pain to either download the code from Github 
https://github.com/dreamdom/Shopping-Cart-Tutorial-part-2

Answer (score 1):

On button `onClick ()` event ..

```
 mCartList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCartList();

 // Make sure to clear the selections
 for(int i=0; i<mCartList.size(); i++) {

      String str = mCartList.get(i).title;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On button onClick() event of ShoppingCartActivity, You can iterate through the all the selected item that is stored in list using following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < mCartList.size(); i++) {
        Product obj = mCartList.get(i);
        Toast.makeText(ShoppingCartActivity.this, obj.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

here, i have displayed titles in tost message, you can also store all these titles in array if you want it  at any other place.